# Kotlin SAM conversion doesn't work for function with two arguments

Tags: android, kotlin, android-livedata

I'm learning Kotlin and trying to use LiveData with it. Since LiveData library is written in Java, Kotlin should support SAM conversions.

[`LiveData`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/LiveData) class has method [`observe`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/LiveData#observe) with two arguments, [`Observer`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/Observer) and [`LifecycleOwner`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/LifecycleOwner):

```java
void observe (LifecycleOwner owner, Observer<T> observer)
```

Both are interfaces with single method. When I use SAM lambdas for both arguments it works fine:

```
val liveData = MutableLiveData<Int>()
liveData.observe({ lifecycleOwner.lifecycle }, { invokeMyMethod(it) })
```

Also it works when I provide object and SAM lambda with specific type (`Observer`):

```
val liveData = MutableLiveData<Int>()
liveData.observe(lifecycleOwner, Observer { invokeMyMethod(it) })
```

However, when I'm trying to use object for one argument and SAM lambda without type for another argument:

```
val liveData = MutableLiveData<Int>()
liveData.observe(lifecycleOwner, { invokeMyMethod(it) })
```

it gives me compilation error. But why I can't write code like this? This is exactly what I want, compact and no boilerplate code. There is only one `observe` method in `LiveData`, why I have to specify the type for lambda?

Compiler produces such error:

> Type mismatch. Required: Observer!>, Found: () → Unit

Small update, I've just checked this combination and it also doesn't work:

```
val liveData = MutableLiveData<Int>()
liveData.observe({ lifecycleOwner.lifecycle }, Observer { invokeMyMethod(it) })
```

So it works when both arguments are SAM lambdas, but doesn't work when one is SAM lambda and another is SAM lambda with specified type. In this case compiler also gives the same `Type mismatch` error.

Comment: What is the exact error message from the compiler?  please edit your question and add that, also if you can post the exact signature of the method `LiveData` and any overrides, that would help.  We don't know where the error really is yet.

Comment: Also can you show the `lifecycleOwner` implementation, because the error could be in a different place, not just with the lambda.

Comment: I think this is the method signature: `observe(LifecycleOwner owner, Observer<T> observer)`

Comment: The error seems to be `type mismatch` on the second argument.  Expected type is `Observer` but what it is being passed is `() -> Unit`

Comment: Jayson Minard, I've just updated my question and added signature and compiler error

Comment: Hold on, apparently `{ owner.lifecycle }` is a valid implementation for `LifecycleOwner.getLifecycle()` which is an interface, so I was previously wrong. But now you got me curious.

Comment: Jayson Minard, as for my variable `lifecycleOwner ` it is declated in this way: `val lifecycleOwner = viewLifecycleOwner`, it is the object returned by `Fragment.getViewLifecycleOwner()` method

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-14984. And according to that, it should finally be fixed in Kotlin 1.3, but the type inference changes required are opt-in for now and need to be enabled explicitly: https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/new-type-inference-in-kotlin-1-3-0-rc-190/9914/2

Answer (score 3):

Your observation seems to be correct, but I won't be able to answer you why.

[image: options]

We see that Kotlin sees either `LifecycleOwner, Observer` or `() -> Lifecycle, (Int?) -> Unit`. As for why you don't see one with *each combination*, only people who work on Kotlin would know!

---

However, I'll be able to give you a workaround.

Add this extension function to your project:

```
inline fun <T> LiveData<T>.observe(lifecycleOwner: LifecycleOwner, crossinline observer: (T?) -> Unit) {
    observe(lifecycleOwner, Observer { observer(it) })
}
```

And now it'll magically work (assuming your extension function is imported)!

```
fun blah() {
    liveData.observe(lifecycleOwner) { // <-- trailing lambda
        invokeMyMethod(it)
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there any reason you have the observer function accepting a nullable parameter? `LiveData<T>` should only emit `T` values.

Comment: Technically it is a platform type, you can instead provide `(T) -> Unit` and don't call it if `it` is null.

Answer (score 0):

the Good news is now kotlin properly handles SAM conversion for functions with multiple arguments.

```
observe(@NonNull LifecycleOwner owner, @NonNull Observer<? super T> observer)
```

Just update to latest live data version, they also [deprecated](https://android-review.googlesource.com/c/platform/frameworks/support/+/1413815/1) the current observe

Example:

```
livedata.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, ::bindData)

private fun bindData(unit: Unit) { }
```